# AWK : To print data of a file in sorted order of result obtained from columns

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, awk, logic

I have an input file that looks somewhat like this:

```
PlayerId,Name,Score1,Score2
1,A,40,20
2,B,30,10
3,C,25,28
```

I want to write an awk command that checks for players with sum of scores greater than 50 and outputs the PlayerId,and PlayerName in sorted order of their total score.

When I try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}{$5=$3+$4;if($5>50) print $1,$2}' | sort -k5
```

It does not work and seemingly sorts them on the basis of their ids.

```
1 A
3 C
```

Whereas the correct output I'm expecting is : ( since Player A has sum of scores=60, and C has sum of scores=53, and we want the output to be sorted in ascending order )

```
3 C
1 A
```

In addition to this,what confuses me a bit is when I try to sort it on the basis of score1, i.e. column 3 but intend to print only the corresponding ids and names, it dosen't work either.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}{$5=$3+$4;if($5>50) print $1,$2}' | sort -k3
```

And outputs :

```
1 A
3 C
```

But if the $3 with respect to what the data is being sorted is included in the print,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}{$5=$3+$4;if($5>50)print $1,$2,$3}' | sort -k3
```

It produces the correct output ( but includes the unwanted score1 parameter in display )

```
3 C 25
1 A 40
```

But what if one wants to only print the id and name fields ?

Actually I'm new to awk commands, and probably I'm not using the sort command correctly. It would be really helpful if someone could explain.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post exact sample output in your question and let us know then. BTW special thanks to you for adding efforts of yours in form of code in your question.

Comment: You're first command is printing 2 fields (`print $1,$2`) and asking `sort` to sort on the 5th field (`sort -k5`). Your awk script assigns a value to a 5th field but you don't print it.

Comment: Yes, @EdMorton, then does it mean that in awk whenever we sort a field it must be included in the print statement ?...but what if I don't intend to print that field ?

Comment: You're mixing 2 completely different tools - awk and shell. The shell is calling `awk` and then that same shell is calling `sort` on the output from awk. For `sort` to sort on a field, that field has to be present in it's input. Given that, `awk` has to output a field for `sort` to sort on. If you don't want to see that field in your final output then you need to remove it again after `sort` is done using it by piping `sort`s output to some additional tool such as `cut` or `sed` or a second call to `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {sum=$3+$4} sum>50{print sum,$1,$2}' file |
    sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
3 C
1 A
```

You have to print the sum so you can sort by it and then the `cut` removes it.

If you wanted the header output too then it'd be:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {sum=$3+$4} (NR==1) || (sum>50){print (NR>1),sum,$1,$2}' file |
    sort -k1,2n | cut -d' ' -f3-
PlayerId Name
3 C
1 A
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ed Morton...just one question, when we say sort -n, I know we're going for numerical sort, so whenever we don't specify a field number using -k5 or -k3 or something, then it's implied that we're sorting by the numeric variable ( sum in this case ? )...Is it so ?

Comment: Not exactly, by default `sort` sorts by the whole line starting from first character of line. In this case `-n` just says "sort the line numerically" and because the first field is the number we care about, that's sufficient. I updated my answer to only sort by that first field, it's cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

if you outsource sorting, you need to have the auxiliary values and need to cut it out later, some complication is due to preserve the header.

```
 $ awk -F, 'NR==1 {print s "\t" $1 FS $2; next}
     (s=$3+$4)>50 {print s "\t" $1 FS $2 | "sort -n" }' file | cut -f2

PlayerId,Name
3,C
1,A
```